# Unknown conditional beforeAgent. Valid conditionals are: allOf, anyOf, branch, buildingTag, changeRequest, changelog, changeset, environment, equals

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

when {anyOf{ beforeAgent true; environment name: "IRM_VLM_FACTSET", value: "true"; environment name: "env1", value: "true"; environment name: "env2", value: "true"; environment name: "env3", value: "true"}}

this is giving me error . Can you tell me what wrong i am doing

Answer (score -1):

when {beforeAgent true; anyOf{ environment name: "IRM_VLM_FACTSET", value: "true"; environment name: "env1", value: "true"; environment name: "env2", value: "true"; environment name: "env3", value: "true"}}